Huygens' trigonometric inequality
Prove that $$1-(4/3(\sin^3 \theta/2))/(\theta-\sin\theta)<(1-\cos\theta/2)(3/5-(3/1400)\pi^2/n^2)$$ holds for $0\le\theta\le\pi/2.$  Here $n$ is an integer greater than or equal to two.
This an unproved inequality due to Christian Huygens. I am preparing a paper on his approximations to $\pi$ and this is an inequality which he stated without proof in his famous work "Inventa."  I have been unable to prove it and I would like to include a proof in my paper.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What is $n$ here?

$n$ is a positive integer.

Any positive integer? Then you can remove the term with $n$, by letting $n\to\infty$.

Where did you get this inequality from?

@IosifPinelis, re, the question says that it is stated without proof in Inventa, I guess meaning De Circuli Magnitudine Inventa.

It is proposition XX in the "Inventa." Huygens says that he obtained it from a more detailed study of the position of the barycenter of a circular segment.  Unfortunately, he never gave any details...the inequality as stated here is the beginning of the asymptotic expansion of the quotient of the left-hand side by the trigonometric function on the right.

here is proposition XX, I can't find anything that looks like this inequality, where is it? https://www.digitale-sammlungen.de/en/view/bsb10053551?page=52,53  what is known as Huygens' inequality is $$2\sin x + \tan x >3x$$

It is on page 41 of your reference.  The inequality you cite is due to Snell...Huygens published the first correct proof.

@MarkBVillarino Where on that page is the number 1400 mentioned?

$\newcommand\th\theta$This inequality is false for $n\ge2$. For instance, the difference between its left and right sides is $<-0.0000589\dots<0$ for $\theta=\pi/2$ and $n=2$ (and hence for all $n\ge2$).

We see that the inequality may be wrong "only slightly". Here is a correct version of the inequality. Replace $3/5-(3/1400)\pi^2/n^2$ in the OP by $c\in(0,3/5]$ and use the substitution
$$t=\tan\frac\th4,\quad \sin\frac\th2=\frac{2t}{1+t^2},
\quad \cos\frac\th2=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},
\quad \sin\th=\frac{4t(1-t^2)}{(1+t^2)^2},
\quad \th=4\tan^{-1}t$$
to rewrite the inequality in question as
\begin{equation*}
    f(t):=f_c(t):=4 \tan ^{-1}(t)
    -\frac{4t \left(1-t^2\right)}{\left(1+t^2\right)^2}
-\frac{32 t^3}{3 (1+t^2)^2 (1-(2 c-1) t^2)}>0   \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
for all
\begin{equation*}
    t\in(0,t_*],\quad t_*:=\tan\frac\pi8=\sqrt{2}-1. 
\end{equation*}
We have
\begin{equation*}
    g(t):=g_c(t):=f'(t)\frac{3(1+t^2)^3(1-(2 c-1) t^2)^2}{64t^4}
    =3 - 5 c + (3 - 9 c + 6 c^2) t^2. 
\end{equation*}
So, letting
\begin{equation*}
    c_*:=\frac{1}{6} \left(12+5 \sqrt{2}-\sqrt{122+84 \sqrt{2}}\right)=0.59225\ldots,
\end{equation*}
we see that $f_c$ is increasing on $(0,t_*)$ if $c\in(0,c_*]$, and, for some $t_1\in(0,t_*)$,  $f_c$ is increasing on $(0,t_1]$ and decreasing on $[t_1,t_*]$ if $c\in(c_*,3/5)$. Also, $f_c(0)=0$.
So, $f_c>0$ on $(0,t_*]$ iff $f_c(t_*)>0$, which latter occurs iff
\begin{equation*}
    c<c_{**}:=\frac{12+4 \sqrt{2}-6 \pi }{12-6 \sqrt{2}-6 \pi +3 \sqrt{2} \pi }
    =0.59451\ldots. 
\end{equation*}
That is, the corrected inequality, with $c$ in place of $3/5-(3/1400)\pi^2/n^2$, holds for all $\th\in(0,\pi/2]$ iff $c<c_{**}=0.59451\ldots$; the latter number is just a bit less than $3/5$.

After this answer was posted, the OP changed the inequality to its opposite, thus invalidating the answer. The role of $n$ remains unexplained by the OP.
So, to answer the changed question, we will again replace $3/5-(3/1400)\pi^2/n^2$ in the OP by $c\in(0,3/5]$ and consider the inequality opposite to \eqref{10}:
\begin{equation*}
    f(t)=f_c(t)<0   \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}
for all $t\in(0,t_*]$.
As noted above, $f_c(0)=0$ and $f_c$ is increasing in a right neighborhood of $0$ if $c\in(0,3/5)$. So, \eqref{20} fails to hold for all $t\in(0,t_*]$ if $c\in(0,3/5)$. On the other hand,
\begin{equation}
    f'_{3/5}(t)=-\frac{128 t^6}{\left(5-t^2\right)^2 \left(t^2+1\right)^3}<0
\end{equation}
for $t\in(0,t_*]$. Therefore and because $f_{3/5}(0)=0$, we see that \eqref{20} holds for $c=3/5$ and all $t\in(0,t_*]$ and, moreover, $3/5$ is the best (that is, the smallest) value of $c$ for which \eqref{20} holds for all $t\in(0,t_*]$.
Thus, inequality \eqref{10} holds for some $c\in(0,3/5]$ and all $t\in(0,t_*]$ iff $c<c_{**}=0.59451\ldots$, and the opposite inequality \eqref{20} holds for some $c\in(0,3/5]$ and all $t\in(0,t_*]$ iff $c=3/5=0.60000\ldots$. We see that the discrepancy between the optimal values $0.59451\ldots$ and $0.60000\ldots$ is small.

Yes, you are right.  The stated inequality is invalid.

The analysis is marvelous.  Unfortunately, I have the inequality backwards, it should be LESS THAN instead of GREATER than.  The asymptotic expansion gives the right-hand side =3/5 -several positive terms.  The first is $(3/1400)\pi^2/n^2$.

@MarkBVillarino : (i) Once again, what is $n$? (ii) You should not change the question so as to to invalidate a valid answer. So, please roll back the change, and let us wrap up this matter. You may then want to post the changed question elsewhere.

@LSpice : Yes, of course. This is now fixed. Thank you for your comment.

Your answer to my incorrect inequality is wonderful.  It shows just how delicate Huygens' inequality is.  However, my mistake in giving the sense of the inequality should not invalidate the entire question.  I admit the error, I changed the inequality sign, and request help.  I admire your ingenious analysis, but my question, corrected, still remains without an answer.

@MarkBVillarino : The matter is, not invalidating the question, but invalidating the answer. So, why not post the changed question elsewhere? I think the same kind of technique could be used for the  changed question -- provided, of course, that you finally answer what $n$ is doing here.

@MarkBVillarino : I have answered your changed question as well, because it required only a relatively small addition to the previous version of the answer. Nonetheless, you should never change the question so as to to invalidate a valid answer. Instead, you should assume responsibility for your mistake (if that was a mistake) when posting the original question. Moreover, you should very carefully recheck your question before posting it, so as not to waste other people's time.

The mysterious role of $n$ seems now to have been clarified.


Prove that $$1-(4/3(\sin^3 \theta/2))/(\theta-\sin\theta)<(1-\cos\theta/2)(3/5-(3/1400)\pi^2/n^2)$$
holds for $0\le\theta\le\pi/2.$  Here $n$ is an integer greater than
or equal to two.

I'm afraid the new inequality is also false. The function $f(\theta)$ = right-hand-side minus left-hand-side has the small-$\theta$ expansion
$$f(\theta)=-\frac{3 \pi ^2\theta^2}{11200 n^2}+{\cal O}(\theta^4),$$
so it is negative at small $\theta$ for any integer $n$, violating the inequality.
I am curious to know what Huygens actually wrote, I am unable to extract the inequality from the Latin source. Perhaps he was merely pointing out a close approximation. (I note that the inequality is only violated slightly.)

After entering my addendum I noticed that Iosif Pinelis has reached the same conclusion in a separate post --- and moreover given a proof. All credit to him.
Addendum: Rescuing the Huygens identity
The appearance of the integer $n$ in Huygens' identity is puzzling, and the fact that it is mistaken is embarassing. I think the way to understand the identity is that $\theta$ and $n$ are not independent: Huygens writes his formulas with reference to an $n$-sided polygon inscribed in the unit circle, in terms of its perimeter $p_n=2n\sin\theta$, $\theta=\pi/n$. It therefore makes sense to understand the inequality upon substitution of $\pi/n\mapsto \theta$,
$$1-\frac{(4/3)\sin^3 \theta/2}{\theta-\sin\theta}<(1-\cos\theta/2)(3/5-(3/1400)\theta^2).$$
Now the small-$\theta$ expansion of the function $g(\theta)=$ right-hand-side minus left-hand-side is positive,
$$g(\theta)=\frac{11}{2688000}\theta^6+{\cal O}(\theta^8).$$
Here is a plot of $g(\theta)$:


What does "the small-$\theta$ of" a function mean? Its Taylor series at $\theta = 0$?

I had left out the word "expansion", corrected, thanks.

Defining the difference $$dif(\theta,n) =1-(4/3(\sin^3 \theta/2))/(\theta-\sin\theta)-(1-\cos\theta/2)(3/5-(3/1400)\pi^2/n^2)$$
We get approximately$$dif(1,2) = 0.000381$$
$$dif(\pi/2,2) = -0.000059$$
The first value is positive, so the conjectured inequality is false.

The $\pi/n$ should read $\theta$, then it holds.

@Carlo Huh? No. I evaluated dif(theta,n) for n=2 at theta = 1, and at theta=pi/2, so what's the problem?

This is the correct inequality: $$1-\frac{(4/3)\sin^3 \theta/2}{\theta-\sin\theta}<(1-\cos\theta/2)(3/5-(3/1400)\theta^2).$$

@Carlo no, please look again at the question... The replacement of pi/n by theta is entirely your alteration of the original problem (in your addendum).
